# Complex jquery selector that looks for a token in a string.split

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an html table where one of the columns contains `<span>`s with comma-delimited data.  I want to come up with a jQuery selector that returns all of the rows (`<tr>`s are preferable, but the `<span>`s will work for now) where one of the comma-delimited tokens `<span>` in a span tag matches a supplied string.

I started with something like the following:

```
$('td.col_8 span:contains("duck")')
```

which will get me all spans in a particular column containing the word 'duck'.  However, it could also match `<span>fox, mallard-duck</span>`. Since 'duck' is not a unique token in that span, I wouldn't want that included in the match.

Is there a way to narrow my result set so I'm only including results where there's an exact match to a particular token in a column-delimited list?

(I'm using jQuery 1.2.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the beauty of jQuery expressions come in.

You can add your own custom selector. I'm going to call it tag in this case

```
jQuery.expr[":"].tag = function(elem, index, match, nodeList) {
    var tags = $(elem).text().replace(/(?:\ +)?,(?:\ +)?/g, ",").split(",");
    return tags.indexOf(match[3]) > -1;
}
```

This will check each previously matched element against this selector. Fist it flattens the , seperations (so something like "firstTag ,    onotherer, badly   , spaced, tag" will work). jQuery already takes care of parsing the selector and passes it in as match. match[3] is what you're interested in. With the following usage match[3] will be 'duck'

```
$('td.col_8 span:tag("duck")')
```

the return line will return true of false based on the tag being in the list.

Comment: That's really cool. There's some serious RegEx-fu going on in there :-).

Comment: Its actually pretty simple. (?: ) is a non-matching group. \ + is any number of spaces. So (?:\ +)? is zero or more spaces, non matched. So this removes spaces around a comma but will leave spaces in a tag alone.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! When you break it down like that, it's not so bad. I get easily intimidated by regex because I still don't know what all of the characters mean just by looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it

```
$('td.col_8 span').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text().match(/^duck$/); 
});
```

Now you just need to define the regex that you need, or implement a string split and array search to return a boolean value to indicate if the `<span>` should be included.

Comment: Ah, `.filter`. I think that's exactly what I needed. If I don't use a regEx, I think I can still split the string and test for equality in the array elements. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like that would only work if duck was the only keyword in the span.

Comment: Note that using `/^duck$/.test($(this).text())` is a little more efficient.

Comment: @James - exactly. This was just a demo to show how it could be done. I'll leave it to Ben to come up with the regex he needs or string splitting / array search implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of [Russ Cam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208097/complex-jquery-selector-that-looks-for-a-token-in-a-string-split/6208123#6208123), here's what I came up with:

```
$('td.col_8 span').filter(function() { 
  return $.inArray('quiet',$(this).html().split(', ')) !== -1;
});
```

Of course, this assumes that the list will always be delimited with `,[space]`, but it should work for my immediate use case.